# Workflow Manager 2013 - Changed the password for the RunAs Account - Workflows not starting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager

I needed to change the account that are running my Workflow Manager services.

Logged into the server running the service and used the following PowerShell using the account that installed Workflow Manager and ran it successfully.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "NotMyActualPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
Stop-SBFarm
Update-SBHost -RunAsPassword $password
Update-WFHost -RunAsPassword $password
Start-SBFarm
```

Services restarted, ran an IISReset just to be sure.

However, now my workflow's are just at a "Not Started" status. Triggering a workflow to manually start just ques up another instance of the workflow. No specific errors show up in the event viewer.

Any pointers to what could be wrong? Anything that's need to be updated from SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop workflow service as well to update the password like this.

**For Service Bus**

```
Import-Module ServiceBus

Stop-SBHost

$mypassword = ConvertTo-SecureString ‘tpas2jupa’ -AsPlainText -Force

Update-SBHost -RunAsPassword $mypassword

Start-SBHost
```

For WorkFlow

```
Stop-WFHost

$mypassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string “password” -force –AsPlainText;

Update-WFHost -RunAsPassword $mypassword

Start-WFHost
```

Here is my post: http://krossfarm.com/?p=1050

Comment: Thank you for taking you time Waqas. While your method are more correct and structured, mine above worked but required a server restart to solve my issue. Guess it was something with all the services running with my account that needed to be updated. Thanks again!